# MSSQL Transferring data between filegroups

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a MSSQL Server database with a huge table that contains sales (~2Million rows).
The structure of the table is (id(PK),operation_date, operation_value).

The goal is to store the last 180 days of data.

I have created 2 files, 2 filegroups(cur_data, archived_data), partition scheme and partition function and it works perfect. But I want to move data from cur_data to archived_data dynamically based on current timestamp - 180 days (that I managed to do in insert trigger), but in this case old data continue to store  cur_data filegroup.

How can I transfer (move) data to archived_data filegroup?

Comment: Why are you doing this in an insert trigger? This is more of a maintenance scheduled job. Write a script to copy the data, then you would delete what you just copied. If you schedule it daily, then the load wouldn't be as great.

Comment: I agree, this is what SQL Server's Agent is for; scheduling nightly maintenance jobs with an INSERT and a DELETE bound inside a transaction.